# program using reflection run as hadoop jar throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hadoop, reflection, jar

I have a base and sub class. The requirement is to invoke sub class' method using reflection. Both programs are below.

base.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
public class base {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URLClassLoader loader = null;
        Class<?> cls;

        try {
            File file = new File("sub.jar" );
            URL[] urls = { file.toURI().toURL() };
            loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            cls = loader.loadClass("sub");
            base obj =  (base) cls.newInstance();

            obj.print();

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured:" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("In Base class");
    }
}
```

---

sub.java

```
public class sub extends base {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("In subclass");
    }
}
```

---

compile both in to jars.

```
javac base.java;
jar cvf base.jar base.class

javac sub.java;
jar cvf sub.jar sub.class
```

If I invoke the base.jar as "java -cp", it works fine

```
java -cp base.jar base 
output: "In subclass"
```

But if I invoke it with "hadoop jar" command, I get

```
hadoop jar base.jar base

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: base
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at base.main(base.java:15)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: base
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is on line 15 where you try to case the loader as your base class. I believe the compiler doesn't know how to handle that. Additionally, I'm not sure why you're trying to run this program with Hadoop since it does not have any of the hadoop implementations or classes

Comment: Marty, I stripped my programs down to simple code without hadoop classes just to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by placing base.jar in hadoop classpath. Run "hadoop classpath" command which lists all classpath dirs. Place the jar in one of these directories.